# What to do in the case of fsockopen error in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, cron

```
try {
    $fp = fsockopen($site, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Why is the `catch` not working, while I'm see that warnings are given for `fsockopen`

> Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

and

> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to [www.myrandsitedf.net:80](http://www.myrandsitedf.net:80) (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. )`

I know that I can use `@` to suppress the error/warning messages, but I don't think that this is the right way to handle an error.

Also the Cronjob at my host doesn't allow PHP files with errors in it, `@` doesn't solve it.

Comment: because PHP procedural functions **NEVER** throw exceptions. They return boolean false on failure. Having functions suddenly start throwing exceptions would break every single "old" script written with the fail-by-boolean methodology. Exactly as [documented](http://php.net/fsockopen): `If the call fails, it will return FALSE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the difference between `exceptions` and `errors`.
If you want errors (warning, etc...) to be transformed into exception such that they can be caught in the catch, you should register a `error_handler` that converts the error into an exception:

```
function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if( ($errno & error_reporting()) > 0 )
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, 500, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
    else
        return false;
}
set_error_handler('error_handler');
```

Comment: How would I use that with my example above? I'm quite new to PHP if there are `warnings` I want the script to continue and not stop , `@` doesn't do the trick for me.

Comment: If you want to ignore warnings, this is a different story. Use the `error_reporting(0)` function as detailed in http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php but anyway the current warning tells you that the host is not found, so you cannot continue anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the exception with global namespace.

Try this code:

```
try {
    $fp = fsockopen($site, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
}
catch(\Exception $ex) { //used back-slash for global namespace
    echo 'error';
}
```

This will work in php 5.3 or later.

Thanks.

Comment: `fsockopen` doesn't throw any exceptions as seen by [marc b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096022/what-to-do-in-the-case-of-fsockopen-error-in-php#comment67464832_40096022)'s comment and the documentation